# Python Problems Connecting to Oracle (cx_Oracle and Pyodbc)

Tags: python, oracle, odbc, pyodbc, cx-oracle

Using Python 3.4 to connect to Oracle 11 (64 bit) but I can't seem to get a connection no matter what I try. I've tried both the cx_Oracle package and the pyodbc package with no success.

Attempts with cx_Oracle

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@server')
```

and

```
        oradsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, server)
        conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user="username, password=password, dsn=oradsn")
```

Error: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle

---

Attempts with pyodbc

```
conn = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ORACLE ODBC DRIVER};DBQ=dsn name;UID=username;PWD=password')
```

and

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=dsn;SERVER=server;UID=username;PWD=password')
```

Error: Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 1114: A dynamic link library (DDL) initialization routine failed.   (<---- sqora32.dll is in that location, I've checked)

---

Environment Variable:

```
ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle\Ora11_x64
```

---

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue ended up being with pyinstaller being used with Cx_oracle. I was creating a single executable file from my python script and it turns out that pyinstaller was including an OCI.dll file. Once I altered Pyinstaller to remove that file everything connected fine on the other system with the executable.

More information here: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2014-December/103608.html

^^In the above example he is adding a .dll file, but I found mine to work by removing the OCI.dll file and disregarding the other one he is talking about

And how to alter pyinstaller: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#using-spec-files

Answer (score 0):

First, on Windows, do not use the environment variable ORACLE_HOME. That should only be used on Linux/Unix platforms. You should instead use the PATH environment variable.

Second, make use of SQL*Plus to confirm that you are able to connect to the database. There are quite a few pages that discuss how to do this. Here is one:

http://penguinman-techtalk.blogspot.ca/2009/02/sqlplus-connection-to-remote-oracle.html

Finally, if you want to use makedsn you need to do the following:

```
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, server)
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user, pwd, dsn)
```

And if you simply want to connect to a database referenced by a local tnsnames.ora file (called tnsentry) you can do the following:

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user, pwd, tnsentry)
```

OR

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect("user/pwd@tnsentry")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Few questions:

1. What should the PATH variable look like?

2. I can't connect through SQL Plus (TNS Adapter error(?)). I CAN however connect through Oracle SQL Developer. Not sure what this means.

Comment: The PATH environment variable should include the location of your SQL*Plus executable and client libraries. SQL Developer uses Java whereas SQL*Plus (and cx_Oracle) use the OCI, so they use somewhat different methods for connecting. TNS adapter error simply means you got the connect string wrong. If you provide details of how you are connecting that might help me help you further. :-)

Comment: Okay I changed my connection string around and was able to connect to SQLPlus! Good news. BUT I still am getting the 'Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle error. my PATH variable has 'C:\Oracle\Ora11_x64\BIN' in the string. I should mention that the tnsnames.ora file does NOT contain my connection and I do not have access rights to change that file. Will I still be able to connect using Cx_oracle?

Comment: I should also mention that I am using pyinstaller to create one .exe file and running that on a different system (where oracle is installed)

Comment: SOLVED: The issue was that pyinstaller was bringing in an OCI.dll file when creating an executable. Connection works once I remove that OCI.dll file from being included in the pyinstaller freeze. More information here: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2014-December/103608.html